# How to interact with a UITableView displayed overlapping another UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have one UITableView displaying some data, and when the user begins typing in a UITextField above the UITableView, another UITableView is displayed below the UITextField to show suggestions.  This "suggestions" UITableView overlaps the UITableView below the UITextField.  Tapping on one of the suggestions will populate the text box with the item tapped.

The suggestions UITableView displays in front of the other UITableView, but problem is that none of the taps to the suggestions UITableView register if they're outside the bounds of the view that contains it.

This is probably a really simple problem dealing more with UIViews in general, but I'm having trouble.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adjust your second tableview which is giving you suggestions below testfield which will solve most of your issues

hope it helps you

Comment: This led me in the right direction--I wound up resizing the frame of the UIView that contains the UITextField and suggestions UITableView based on the size of the suggestions UITableView, then setting the frame back to the original size when the suggestions view is dismissed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can show the second UITableView within another view that is displayed above the current view, like a popover, using

```
[self.view addSubview:secondView].
```

Once a selection is made, you can remove this view using

```
[secondView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't appear to address the issue I'm seeing.  I still have to resize the frame of the UIView containing both controls in order to interact with the suggestions UITableView.  I wonder if it's better (performance or memory usage) to hide and show the suggestions or to add its view and then remove it from the superview as you've suggested?